# Is there a way to check the day an article was published on an arbitrary website?

Tags: language-agnostic, web

I'd like to do this without "scraping" the page, even if there's a way that isn't strictly universal. After some looking around, I found that you can get the last-modified date from the headers, but I found that to be pretty useless because for many sites, the date returned is just seconds in the past. This seems to be because of some small changes on the page (like comments).

Comment: have you checked if the articles are published in an rss feed?

Comment: I'm trying to do this for arbitrary sites that may or may not have an RSS feed.

Comment: But I think that's actually something to look into.

Comment: If the page is being generated dynamically by a script without special caching, the HTTP Last-Modified header will always be the current time. It's a low-level mechanism used by browser and proxy caches, not really for human consumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the site offers an atom feed, it should have the published date. For example, [the feed for your question](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/19384363) has:

```
    # removed stuff
    <entry>
        # trimmed some more stuff
        <author>
            <name>Hassan</name>
            <uri>https://stackoverflow.com/users/377628</uri>
        </author>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384363/is-there-a-way-to-check-the-day-an-article-was-published-on-an-arbitrary-website" />
        <published>2013-10-15T14:52:55Z</published>
        <updated>2013-10-15T14:52:55Z</updated>
        # more stuff here
```

Comment: Looking for an atom feed rules out any arbitrary site, and restricts functionality to those sites that have one. Since most sites don't include such a feed this is of little practical use within the context of the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

To be avalable reliably on any site, any given piece of information must be part of the HTTP header block. There is no HTTP header for 'First Published' or 'Created' or anything similar. The best available is 'Last-Modified', since that's the only value that has meaning within the context of HTTP.

To illustrate, a static page might have a file-system creation date, but the entire content could have been replaced. The filesystem 'creation date' needn't change, but the last-modified date will. Similarly for dynamically created pages, the software creating the page would have to rely on some date within the system, but again, the content could have been partially or completely replaced after creation. The difficulty would be deciding at what point the changes constitue a newly-published page, or just a modified version of an old one.

Some syndication formats (like Atom or RSS) may include a 'publication date' in their content, but this won't be part of the HTTP haders, and therefore not available on any arbitrary site, as per your question.

You can find the HTTP header reference [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: +1, a lot of good information here. The RSS/Atom option looks appealing though, because although it's not universal, it does cover "most" sites which host articles and provides reliable dates.